Bolded number "1" next to chat room when visiting chat.stackexchange.com on mobile
When browsing https://chat.stackexchange.com/ on mobile (Safari in my particular case), I see a bolded "1" next to the Teacher's Lounge room:

The bold "1" does not appear when browsing from a Desktop.
The bold "1" does not appear when browsing on mobile after explicitly requesting "Desktop view", but then reappears after clicking the "mobile" link in the footer.
I've ruled out ping-replies and flagged messages as the possible reason, so: any ideas what this bolded "1" means?

I'm aware there's current activity around chat -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/404568/307535 -- but nothing in that announcement jumps out to me as affecting only mobile views.

There's also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/404718/307535 where a bug was fixed in the TL, but that doesn't scream "mobile-only", either.

Confirmed that I see the bolded "1" on a Desktop browser after requesting the "mobile" view.

Opened this up in Chrome's inspect element. This appears to be an indicator that there's a moderator flag. The element is:
<span title="Flagged for moderator attention" class="flag-indicator mod-flag">1</span>

This is odd functionality because at this level you're still considered a moderator in chat (and thus likely able to see flags), but because the TL only lets CMs and certain mods have mod privileges in it, you can't actually see flags raised there, so navigating into the chatroom won't show any flags as needing attention. I suspect this is just an issue with the mobile view being old and not handling the "Moderated private room" status that the TL has properly.

Actually more likely it used to work properly and was broken after the migration to GCP, same as The whois feature in TL is currently broken bug. (Otherwise I'd expect it would have been noticed before)

@ShadowWizard I remember seeing this in 2023 (and maybe before that?), so it's not related to the migration. I wouldn't complain if they fixed it with all those issues, however.

I don't think this is GCP migration related, @ShadowWizard. Flags in the TL are just very rare and don't usually stick around for long. It's just a bit of custom code for that room, not too surprised there's a small blip in how it operates.

Agree. I see no way this would be migration-related.
